# Python Tkinter - Tcl Error

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote this class with two methods:

```
import tkinter, random

class MojaGrafika:
    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=400, height=300)
        self.canvas.pack()

    def text(self, text, x, y, farba=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.t = text
        self.canvas.create_text(self.x, self.y, text=self.t)
```

Then I run it (g = MojaGrafika(), g.text(200, 150, 'P', 'red')) 
and this error came up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    g.text(200, 150, 'P', 'red')
  File "C:\Users\zuzha\Documents\Cvicenia z programovania 2016\ZS\15.cvicenie.py", line 102, in text
self.p = self.canvas.create_text(self.x, self.y, text=self.t)
  File "C:\Users\zuzha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2344, in create_text
return self._create('text', args, kw)
  File "C:\Users\zuzha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2320, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance "P"
```

Can somebody help me with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(English)

You declare method with arguments

```
text(text, x, y, farba)
```

but then you call arguments in wrong order

```
text(x, y, text, farba)
```

see

```
g.text(200, 150, 'P', 'red')
```

so `create_text()` tries to use value `P` as `x`

---

(Polish) Zła kolejność argumentów

Comment: is that last sentence  (`PL: Zła kolejność argumentów`) somehow part of the answer??

Comment: @BryanOakley yes it answer in Polish - I see OP use Polish words in code.